# Сохранить состояние ToggleButton для каждого элемента listview отдельно

Tags: android, listview, toggle

Я запускаю новую активити по клику на элемент списка. В каждой из этих активити есть кнопка-переключатель. Я пытаюсь сохранить эту кнопку в том состоянии, в котором ее оставил пользователь, для каждого элемента списка отдельно. Нечто вроде кнопки "Мне нравится". Посоветовали обратить внимание на setTag, getTag. Но не могу найти ни одного примера его использования для ToggleButton.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.one_event);

btnAddToList = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAddToList);
btnAddToList.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton toggleButton, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked) {
            addEventToList();
            scheduleNotification(getNotification("The Event begin soon"), 7200000);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(OneEvent.this, id_favorite_event, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        };
    }
});
}
```

[image: скрин №1]

[image: Скрин №2]

Comment: Не увидел связи скрина и кода с вопросом. По нажатию на элемент в `ListView` открывается `Activity`? В `ListView` должна быть индикация вкл/выкл?

Comment: @VAndrJ Список выглядит как на скрине №2. по клику на элемент открывается активити (скрин №1). Кнопка вкл/выкл - кнопка с сердечком

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По нажатию на кнопку(вкл) Вы должны каким-либо образом сохранить данные об этом. Как вижу, `addEventToList();` у Вас. В этом методе и сохраняйте. Когда нажимаете снова(выкл), то удаляйте эти данные(ну либо сохраняйте другие значения), сделайте какой-нибудь `removeEventFromList();`, где будете это делать.

При запуске `Activity` проверяйте сохраненное состояние и если да, то "нажимайте" кнопку:

```
btnAddToList = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.btnAddToList);
if(<проверка сохраненного и сохранено, что нажато>) {
    btnAddToList.setChecked(true);
}
btnAddToList.setOnCheckedChangeListener...
```

Comment: Если я, допустим, использую в методе `addEventToList();` использую `btnAddToList.setTag(true);`, а в `removeEventFromList();` - `btnAddToList.setTag(false);`, это должно сработать?

Comment: @FatSlowpoke из самого легкого используйте `SharedPreferences`, если хотите сохранить данные и использовать их и после перезапуска приложения.

Comment: это сработало, но сработало для всех элементов списка одновременно. То есть если я "лайкну" одно, то "лайкнутся" все остальные и наоборот.

Comment: @FatSlowpoke так для каждой кнопки сохраняйте свое значение.

Comment: В том то и дело, что я не понимаю как сохранить его для каждой кнопки, потому что по сути она одна. Определяется только один раз. Различаются лишь id элемента списка.

Comment: Получилось, обращаюсь по id элемента списка. Большое спасибо за помощь

Comment: @FatSlowpoke Лучшая практика здесь, поскольку вы используете модель, создать в этой модели поле для хранения текущего состояния лайкнутости каждой записи, потом читать из этого поля и ставить соответственное состояние на экране. SharedPreferences для такого не использует никто и теги кнопок тоже.